# How to Set JavaScript variable inside Jsp Code

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

I would like to know that how can i set javascript variable in side Jsp code.

```
    <script type='text/javascript' >

     var result;
     $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/api/report/test',
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function(data) { 
                result= data;     
          } 
          });

     var dataTable = <% 
     out.print(result);
 %>

     </script>
```

Above is my Jsp code.In there i call my REST service to fetch data and print on the page.But when i try to set **result** variable its gave me error.I would like to know that is there any ways to call ajax method inside JSP code or how can i set java script variable inside JSP code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot. The JSP part is serverside, the javascript is client side.

You can only set values serverside if you push them via ajax, but then you will have four steps:

1. Render page with javascript(JSP)
2. Ajax call to JSP page(Javascript)
3. Process values serverside(JSP) and return output
4. Process returned output from JSP to user(JavaScript)

The javascript parts are purely clientside and will be executed by browser. Your server cant do anything with it. as far as your server is concerned its just text.

The JSP parts are server side and run by the server. Whatever the output it compiles is sent to the user.

You cannot "cross" over.

Comment: Is there any way to call REST service with ajax within JSP page?

Comment: You dont need ajax in JSP...  You need to use a Java Method/way to call the proper url, read contents and process it. You might want to look at http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restfull-java-client-with-java-net-url/